# Are these 2 methods started almost at the same time?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

When I run below code, Output is this: 
[image: Output when printed till 500]
When I run till 300, output is this: 
[image: Output when printed till 300]
When I run till 100, output is this: 
[image: Output when printed till 100]

Does this mean that both methods started almost at the same time?

If this is true, why do we need Parallel library if we can achieve parallelism by async-await?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class Program
{
    public static void PrintX()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { Console.Write("x"); }
    }

    public static void PrintY()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { Console.Write("y"); }
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => PrintY());
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => PrintX());
        await t1;
        await t2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Program().RunAsync();
        t.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could fix your code sample to a) be fully indented (either remove the namespace declaration, or indent the class) and b) have meaningful method names? (The CountForward method doesn't count, and the PrintX method prints y...)

Comment: But yes, basically you're getting concurrent execution. TPL allows you to manage things more carefully though, e.g. spreading work items from a single source across a bounded set of tasks etc.

Comment: Lets just say, console output is among the worst possibilities to make concurrency visible. The output needs to be synchronized at some point.

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately you're at the mercy of the thread pool here. You have enqueued two items (`Task.Run`), and they will be picked up and serviced at some future time. When they start is non-deterministic, and will depend on how many available threads there are, and other factors.

They will start *approximately* at the same time, with no guarantees of anything (perhaps not even the order in which they start). The `await` will be triggered against their *completion* - so *when* you call `await` (or even ***whether*** you call `await`) won't impact them in any way. They might run in parallel, but most likely they individually run fast enough that whichever one gets started first will have completed before it tries starting the second. They might even end up running consecutively on the same thread (outputting the managed thread id would be a way to see this).

As for why we need `Parallel`: firstly, it pre-dates `async`/`await` by a long time; secondly it does a lot of things to allow *larger scale* parallelization - things like running a large sequence with concurrent processing including fixed maximum parallelization.

Just to show that it *can* be concurrent, here's the output from a real run where I added the `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` into the output:

```
main: 1
y: 3
x: 4
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

definitely concurrent, but: other runs can show very different outputs

Comment: If I put Thread.Sleep(50) inside both methods, both methods seem to be executed as parallel.

Comment: @Lyrk you can get that even without the sleep - see the edit above; the point is that as soon as you start talking about concurrency you get non-determinism; given A and B, you can get "A then B", "B then A", "A and B running concurrently with A starting first" or "A and B running concurrently with B starting first"

Comment: The thing I do not get is when I start a method with a Task.Run(), it will be started in a different thread guranteed. (This is told like this in microsoft document) So I order the computer to run these two methods in different threads in above code. If instead I put these functions in parallel library, they will  start at different threads and at the same time then what is the difference of achieving this by parallel library instead of async-await? I mean if both start at different threads what is the difference?

Comment: @Lyrk again: the `Parallel` type is intended for non-trivial parallelization scenarios. What you have here is a trivial parallelization scenario, so it won't be a surprise that `Parallel` doesn't offer much to change it. Additionally: there is **absolutely not** even a remote guarantee of "and at the same time" - when they start is non-deterministic. They will start *at some time* - that's all you know. The big differences for `Parallel` comes when you're working on large data sets: you *do not* want to start 20,000 tasks (that would be very very bad), and you *do* want some amount of...

Comment: ...thread/data locality to avoid the number of page-faults etc; similarly, you want things like work stealing, bounded parallelization ("max DoP"), co-ordinated handling of zero, one or many failures, etc. These are some of the things that `Parallel` brings. It does nothing useful when starting 2 unrelated tasks.

Comment: thanks so much. I thought async-await is much more capable then parallel library but it seems they have different usage.

Comment: @Lyrk oh, *absolutely* different purposes; in everything above, I've been talking about your example of `Task.Run` - but: and this is **absolutely crucial** - `async`/`await` *is not about concurrency* - at least, not for the code that is awaiting/awaited (confusing bit: it *is* about concurrency in that it frees up the executing thread to service *other* operations). The primary intended purpose is for IO-bound out-of-process operations such as network / file access. It *just so happens* that it can also be mapped to some CPU-based parallel actions, but that is just a convenient coincidence.